# Making filled icons outline - mui

Tags: material-ui, material-icons

I am using mui icons, currently I have filled ones but I want the thin versions for all of them.

This is where I am using them:

const drawer = (

```
    <div>
      <div className="drawer-container">
        <div className="menu-container mt-8">
          <List>
            <div>
              <DrawerItem name="Users" link="/view-users" icon="group" subItems={userChildren} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <DrawerItem name="Forms" icon="article" link="/home" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <DrawerItem name="Organisations" icon="groups" link="/organisations" />
            </div>
          </List>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

They look like this:

[image]

My question is how do I get the outline versions?

Comment: Here is the link https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?theme=Outlined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to remove font-family styling from mui-icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73542767/trying-to-remove-font-family-styling-from-mui-icon)